# Dirac measure is $\sigma$-finite

Tags: measure-theory

Just a quick question: Why is the dirac measure $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: By Dirac measure, do you mean $\delta_x(E)=1$ if $x\in E$ and $0$ if $x\notin E$?

Comment: Yes, thats correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dirac mass at a point is a finite measure (a probability measure moreover), hence it is $\sigma$-finite.

To be concrete, if $(X,\mathcal M)$ is a measure space and $x\in X$, let $E_1=X$, and $E_j=\varnothing $ for $j\geq2$.  Then $\{E_j\}$ is a countable collection of measurable sets whose union is $X$, and $\delta_x(E_j)<\infty$ for all $j$.

Comment: I needed the part showing that it is a countable collection of measurable sets whose union is . Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.  By the way, the same argument shows that any finite measure is $\sigma$-finite.